# MySQL + PHP: Group by an ADJUSTED Date

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, utc

I have an interesting case.  I have a set of datetimes and I need to find the minimum for each day.  The database stores them as UTC but they need to be grouped according to (1) the local timezone and (2) a custom "my day starts at XX:XX" field.

For example, if the following is my dataset:

```
+----------+---------------------+
|       id | start               |
+----------+---------------------+
|        1 | 2015-04-26 16:00:00 |
+----------+---------------------+
|        2 | 2015-04-26 17:00:00 |
+----------+---------------------+
|        3 | 2015-04-26 20:00:00 |
+----------+---------------------+
|        4 | 2015-04-27 01:00:00 |
+----------+---------------------+
|        5 | 2015-04-27 16:25:00 |
+----------+---------------------+
|        6 | 2015-04-27 16:35:00 |
+----------+---------------------+
|        7 | 2015-04-28 02:00:00 |
+----------+---------------------+
```

And if the person querying is in New York (UTC+4), and says their day starts at "3:30am" (UTC+4+3:30), then I would need the following results:

```
+----------+---------------------+
|       id | start               |
+----------+---------------------+
|        2 | 2015-04-26 17:00:00 |
+----------+---------------------+
|        6 | 2015-04-27 16:35:00 |
+----------+---------------------+
```

Notice that the times are for the UTC time for the "first" records of the day which start "at or after" the 3:30am time in New York.

Currently my query looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM records GROUP BY DATE(start);
```

I **do** have use of PHP, so is this as simple as calculating the time delta (ex: UTC+4+3:30 => +7.5 hours *OR* +450 minutes) and using `DATE_ADD()`?

**Is this the correct/best way to do it?**

```
SELECT * FROM records GROUP BY DATE(DATE_ADD(start,INTERVAL 450 MINUTE));
```

Comment: No. MySQL can work out the time zone stuff for you. And any time you see a GROUP BY clause with no aggregating functions, alarm bells should start ringing.

Comment: @Strawberry This is a simplified example.  In reality I have a `WHERE` clause and am also grouping by a second column (not listed here) as well.  Do you mean something else by "aggregating functions"?  Could you provide an example?  Also, why (and how) can I have MySQL sort out the timezone stuff?  (My server is all UTC based; the querying user's timezone is stored in a single MySQL field.)